# MySQL - Using table data twice

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've a question regarding a query in MySQL.

At first the table information:

[image: The table 'dier']

My question:
I need the rnaam from vader (which has the dnr value), but also the rnaam of the child.
How can I achieve this?

I tried some subselects without success.

Table content:

[image: Table content]

You can see the column 'vader' in this picture with a dnr code.
For example the second row from this picture has dnr code 39 which is the child of father with dnr code 1.

My query at this moment:

```
select rnaam as rnaam_vader, rnaam as kind, gesl as gesl_kind from dier
    join soort on soort.snr = dier.snr
    where soort.nsnaam = 'chimpansee'
```

Example row:

```
father  child   gender
BIGBOSS POEKIE  V
```

Comment: You're joining on `snr` column, however relations are on `dnr` and `vader` as you said.

Comment: Yes, the query has the condition to show only the rows that are 'chimpansee'. This information is in table 'soort' that's why I join on snr. This is unrelated to my question.

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand you need 2 cols of both child and father : `select f.rnaam as father, c.rnaam as child from dier c inner join dier f on c.dnr = f.vader`

Comment: This is works! But I am not able to add my condition or 'gender' to the outcome. This is what I have now: `select k.rnaam as kind, v.rnaam as vader, dier.gesl from dier v join dier k on v.dnr = k.vader
  join soort on soort.snr = dier.snr
where soort.nsnaam = 'chimpansee'` It gives me the error at `unknown colum at 'dier.gesl' in field list. Just like the chimpansee condition.

Comment: Gender of what? child or father? check this of child: `select k.rnaam as kind, v.rnaam as vader, v.gesl from dier v join dier k on v.dnr = k.vader join soort s on s.snr = v.snr where s.nsnaam = 'chimpansee'`

Comment: I've the outcome I wanted! Can I ask how this method like 'k.rnaam' and 'v.rnaam' is called? Thank in advance!

Comment: I made an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As discussed in comments*:

You are dealing with ***name aliases*** on tables so be careful using aliases that won't make problems in how to refer to them later.

Because of similar column names of father and child *[rnaam]* and ambiguity in requesting *gender* *[gesl]* there should be a discriminant - **that's why aliases are used here.**

```
SELECT 
    k.rnaam as kind,
    v.rnaam as vader,
    v.gesl
        FROM dier v
        JOIN dier k
            ON v.dnr = k.vader
        JOIN soort s
            ON s.snr = v.snr
    where
        s.nsnaam = 'chimpansee'
```

Comment: It is a little bit more clear. I will practice some more with this. Thanks!